# How to use image picker inside recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview to show details of multiple persons, user has a option to upload a image for a person, my issue is how to pick image in recyclerview and get storage permission as onActivityResult only works in activity.

Comment: So what is the issue? What you have tried?

Comment: i tried to use get permission on onBindViewHolder but permission can be recieved in activity only also onActivityResult works in activty i didnt find  a way to pick image from storage

Comment: So call method from activity to adapter or make listener in adapter class

Comment: i can make listener in adapter class no issue but how to call onActivityResult

Comment: Its override method. When you start _startActivityForResult_ override that method

Comment: where should i write code for storage permssion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String  mCurrentPhotoPath ; 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
            switch (requestCode) {
                case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        if (data != null) {
                            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                            String path = null;
                            try {
                                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),contentURI);
                                path = saveImage(bitmap);
                                //   decodeImage(path);
                                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            mCurrentPhotoPath = path;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
}     


public void activeGallery() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

}
```

try this one @user678413,you need to add the permission in activity not in adapter class

Comment: OP wants to access it from adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using below code

```
// Binds each guest in the ArrayList to a view
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.guestNumber.text = "Guest "+ (position+1)
    holder.constraint.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    holder.image.setImageURI(images[position])
    holder.firstName.text = guests[position].name.split(" ").first()
    holder.lastName.text = guests[position].name.split(" ").last()

    holder.image.setOnClickListener{


        requestPermissions(it.context as Activity , arrayOf(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),1)

        this.position=holder.adapterPosition
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        (it.context as Activity).startActivityForResult(intent, 1, Bundle())
        (it.context as Activity).onActivityReenter(1,intent)
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        1 -> {/*file front*/
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                imageList[adapter!!.position!!]  = data.data as Uri
                adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
}
```